# group htmlhelper radio buttons

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would just like to know if there is a way to group html helper radio buttons

```
@Html.RadioButton("uniqueRadio", item.standard_100)
@Html.Label("standard100")
<br />
@Html.RadioButton("uniqueRadio", item.standard_200)
@Html.Label("standard200")
```

What I am trying to do is populate these radio buttons with values from my DB and aloow a user to choose one and pass it back to the controller for further use. This code will be placed in a foreach loop as each record in the DB has 4 columns which values are being populated in the radio buttons.

Any help or advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: So what problem are you having?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Hi Stephen, My question is, From my question I have named both radio butttons "uniqueRadio", When recieving in my controller and request the name "uniqueRadio" would it return the value of the checked radio button?

Comment: Yes it will ...

Comment: Your current code is in the right way, because `Request.Form["uniqueRadio"]` will return selected value in controller. Note that it's better to use a viewmodel property and bind it with `RadioButtonFor` than using `Request.Form` everywhere.